# How to connect multiple thermocouples via amplifier IC, multiplexer to Arduino?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, sensors

My application needs to measure the temperature from 30 sensors, then read data by Arduino. Even if I use Arduino UNO or Arduino Mega, the operating voltage is 5V(UNO), 7~12V(Mega). But thermocouple output voltages are tiny, so I must use amplifier IC (MAX31855) for Arduino analog inputs.

At first, I wanted to use Arduino Mega with 16 analog inputs, then use 1 multiplexer 16-channels (maybe 74HC4067 IC) can meet the requirement of 30 sensor inputs. But now, I can't directly connect thermocouples to 74HC4067. 
As my understanding, I must connect as the following sequence: Thermocouples→ Amplifier→ Multiplexer→ Arduino.

But the problem is: the IC MAX31855 has 3 outputs (DO, CS, CLK). So I don't know how to connect 16 thermocouples to MAX31855 and send data to the multiplexer 74HC4067. Because 16 thermocouples corresponding 16 ICs MAX31855 (48 outputs) to multiplexer. So the 16-channel multiplexer is not enough.

Furthermore, I checked MAX31855 datasheet, we need to connect DO, CS, CLK pins to SPI pins on Arduino. But Arduino only has 1 SPI channel, and I need to use 30 sensors. How can I connect 30 thermocouples to Arduino (UNO or Mega)? Please suggest me.

Comment: This should go on  [electronics.SE]. That being said, have you looked into a possibility of a different amplifier IC, or a suitable analog mux that can switch multiple sensors to one amplifier?

Comment: I would try to use 30 MAX31855. Link all clock and data lines. Give only one MAX31855 its ChipSelect at a time and select so one MAX after the other and read out the sensors one after the other. You may want to use two 4 bit decoders (like 74HC154) to build the chip select signals.

Comment: @user5329483 : How to determine the amount of decoders we need? Does it mean 2^4=16, so each 4 bit decoder can handle 15 channels? Can you send me a reference how to do the coding with 4 bit decoder & Arduino?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use 30 MAX31855. Link all clock and data lines. Give only one MAX31855 its ChipSelect at a time and select one MAX after the other and read out one sensor after the other.

You may want to use two 4 bit decoders (like 74HC154) to build the chip select signals. I made a sketch with a nice interactive circuit simulator found at [falstad.com](http://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html). The six switches are outputs from your arduino, the 32 LEDs representing your chip selects.

[image: Circuit]

Just select in the circuit simulator `File` -> `Import from text` and paste the script below and start toggling the switches.

```
$ 1 0.000005 0.04168620196785084 50 5 50
185 288 -80 480 -80 0 4
s 128 -144 288 -144 0 1 false
s 128 -80 288 -80 0 0 false
s 128 496 320 496 0 1 false
s 128 544 320 544 0 0 false
s 128 592 320 592 0 0 false
s 128 640 320 640 0 1 false
w 320 544 352 544 0
w 320 592 384 592 0
w 320 640 416 640 0
w 320 464 320 496 0
w 352 464 352 544 0
w 384 464 384 592 0
w 416 464 416 640 0
w 128 -144 128 -80 0
w 128 -80 128 496 0
w 128 640 128 592 0
w 128 592 128 544 0
w 128 544 128 496 0
R 128 -80 16 -80 0 0 40 5 0 0 0.5
162 480 -80 592 -80 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 480 -48 592 -48 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 480 -16 592 -16 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 480 80 592 80 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 480 48 592 48 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 480 16 592 16 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 480 112 592 112 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 480 144 592 144 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 480 176 592 176 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 480 400 592 400 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 480 368 592 368 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 480 272 592 272 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 480 304 592 304 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 480 336 592 336 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 480 240 592 240 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 480 208 592 208 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
w 592 -80 592 -48 0
w 592 -48 592 -16 0
w 592 -16 592 16 0
w 592 16 592 48 0
w 592 48 592 80 0
w 592 80 592 112 0
w 592 112 592 144 0
w 592 144 592 176 0
w 592 176 592 208 0
w 592 208 592 240 0
w 592 240 592 272 0
w 592 272 592 304 0
w 592 304 592 336 0
w 592 336 592 368 0
w 592 368 592 400 0
g 592 400 592 480 0
g 944 400 944 480 0
w 944 368 944 400 0
w 944 336 944 368 0
w 944 304 944 336 0
w 944 272 944 304 0
w 944 240 944 272 0
w 944 208 944 240 0
w 944 176 944 208 0
w 944 144 944 176 0
w 944 112 944 144 0
w 944 80 944 112 0
w 944 48 944 80 0
w 944 16 944 48 0
w 944 -16 944 16 0
w 944 -48 944 -16 0
w 944 -80 944 -48 0
162 832 208 944 208 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 832 240 944 240 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 832 336 944 336 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 832 304 944 304 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 832 272 944 272 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 832 368 944 368 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 832 400 944 400 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 832 176 944 176 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 832 144 944 144 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 832 112 944 112 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 832 16 944 16 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 832 48 944 48 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 832 80 944 80 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 832 -16 944 -16 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 832 -48 944 -48 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
162 832 -80 944 -80 2 default-led 1 0 0 0.01
w 768 464 768 640 0
w 736 464 736 592 0
w 704 464 704 544 0
w 672 464 672 496 0
185 640 -80 832 -80 0 4
w 288 -144 640 -144 0
w 640 -144 640 -80 0
w 320 496 672 496 0
w 352 544 704 544 0
w 384 592 736 592 0
w 416 640 768 640 0
```

There should be some resistors there to protect the LEDs, but this is for demonstration only.